# Doctrine 2 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

As part of an application I'm working on, I'm presenting the user with a screen where they can update their account info, address, and profile info. Only the account info is saving, and after I call `$model->profile->populate($_POST['Account_profile']);` I'm calling `die($model->profile->dump());` and getting two errors, both in the Doctrine file `BasicEntityPersister.php`:

`line 1574: Undefined index: visitor`

and

`lie 1579: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I have a feeling this has to do with incorrect relational mapping, but I'm a bit of a noob at Doctrine 2. Anyone know what these errors might mean?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you might be trying to set a field ('visitor') that either isn't in your post index, or not in the entity.

Comment: You're right, another developer changed the name visitor to a new field name. Doctrine was trying to map in a model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your post data that you applied in

```
$model->profile->populate($_POST['Account_profile']);
```

The Post data is same as, that user submit while fill up the form details.

Print the log message just after the same line.

```
i.e: log_message('info',print_r($_POST, TRUE));
```

Hope this will help.